# Can't get COOKIE value after clicking submit button, working only after second clicking

Tags: javascript, php

I've got an issue with using cookie, I've got a form:

```
if( isset($_GET['my_number']) ) {
    $my_text = esc_attr($_GET['my_number']);
}
?>
    <form id="my-form" method="get">
        <input id="my_number" type="number" name="my_number" value="<?php echo $my_number; ?>" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="search">
    </form>
<?php
```

What I want to get value that user would type inside input after pressing submit button and echo this value by cookie and javascript. My javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  const cookieMin = $("#my_number").val();
  createCookie("my_number_cookie", cookieMin, "10");
});

function createCookie(name, value, days) {
  var expires;
  if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
  }
  else {
    expires = "";
  }
  document.cookie = escape(name) + "=" + escape(value) + expires + "; path=/";
}
```

and in my php I'm adding:

```
echo $_COOKIE['my_number_cookie'];
```

And I'm getting this value, but only after second submit button refresh.
I found some questions about that, but their examples too hard to understand for me.

Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you add cookie after first submit is already happend.
So, you will receive it only after the second submit will be made.

To make what you want, you should intercept form submit event and add your cookie in that time (i.e. just before the submit form will be sent).

So, here are the solution:

```js
//Replace that code
$(document).ready(function () {
  const cookieMin = $("#my_number").val();
  createCookie("my_number_cookie", cookieMin, "10");
});

//With this:
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#my-form").submit(function() { //after form is submitted
      const cookieMin = $("#my_number").val(); //took input value
      createCookie("my_number_cookie", cookieMin, "10"); //create your cookie
      //after that form will proceed the submit process, but with cookie added
    });
});
```

Comment: Cookies are set by the `Set-Cookie:` header and therefore you must receive a new HTML page from the host before you'll see it appear.